# Sleep takes too long on Windows 10 April Update(1803). How to force simple S3?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, power-management, windows-10-v1803

I know there is sleep and hybrid sleep. I used to disable hybrid sleep and it worked on the same hardware before. But recently, and I assume it is after the Windows 10 April Update, the sleep started to take really long. When I execute sleep, the screens immediately go off, but the disk LED blinks crazily for about two minutes and then I hear the tick sound from the PSU.

This is annoying because I sleep/awake the PC often, and if I executed sleep by mistake, I cannot immediately awake the PC while the disk LED is crazily blinking (probably writing the memory content to the disk). I suspect it is doing some sort of hybrid sleep, but this is odd. When I executed `powercfg -availablesleepstates`, I only see "Standby (S3)" in the available section, and all other states are in the unavailable section. Indeed, I also ran `powercfg -h off` just to be sure.

But it still does not immediately sleep. How can I disable the disk writing and put the computer to S3 sleep immediately with Windows 10 April Update?

---

Added

It may be due to Chrome, when I kill the Chrome process and then click Sleep, the computer goes to sleep immediately. But when I clicked sleep again after waking it, it took again too. I need to investigate this more.

---

Added 2

This happend on my laptop too. After reinstalling Windows, the problem was gone, and after sometime, it became slow too. I tried to uninstall somethings, and uninstalling the Intel Graphics driver solved it. Windows Update automatically had installed an Intel Graphics driver, but that version was older than the one that manufacturer provided. So I had installed it. I uninstalled that and let Windows Update install the graphics driver, and the sleep delay was gone.

Comment: Please run [powercfg -energy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976034/guided-help-get-a-detailed-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-for-you) and post the results.

Comment: Take a look at this recent question.  At the very least, it has somewhat similar concerns:  [How can I change the Windows 10 1803 shutdown sequence?](https://superuser.com/questions/1331693/how-can-i-change-the-windows-10-1803-shutdown-sequence)

Comment: [analyze the sleep/resume with WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1125117/174557)

Comment: Thank you (plural) for your help. I have tried those tools, but it was difficult to find the cause. So, I guess relatively the easiest way is to reinstall Windows to fix this.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Before you spin your wheels in that direction (extreme solution to an easy problem to solve).  Use Autoruns to boot into a minimal configuration.  Can you reproduce the error at that configuration?

Comment: I have a problem with the exact same symptoms on 1803. It takes A LOT of HDD LED blinking for almost a minute before the system actually does go to sleep, and hybrid sleep is disabled.